# Lua - How to use functions from another script

Tags: lua

I'm wondering how to use functions from another script in Lua. For example, say `GameObjectUtilities` holds functions that many `GameObject` scripts will use. The `Slime` (a `GameObject`) script wants to use a function in `GameObjectUtilities`.

I'm having trouble getting this to work. I've looked [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued), but I still don't really fully understand. Do I need to create a module or a table to hold the functions in `GameObjectUtilities` for the functions in it to be used in other scripts? If so, what is the best way to go about this?

It's very odd. It actually does work when I just do it the normal way. The problem is that when I run my app and it tries to use the script it doesn't work. I don't get it.

Comment: Have you looked at package.path - http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-package.path ? Also, are you sure you don't get any errors from Lua, maybe you are somehow ignoring them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you don't have to create a module. If you just create `foo.lua` like this:

```
function double(n)
  return n * 2
end
```

And then in your script, `require 'foo'`, you will be able to access the `double` function just like it was defined in the same script. Those functions can't get at your locals, but they are created in the same environment -- all `module 'name'` does is create a new table and reset the current environment to that table.

So, you can just do:

```
function slimefunc(...) stuff() end
```

In `GameObjectUtils.lua`, and if you `require 'GameObjectUtils'`, then `Slime` can just use `slimefunc`. Or, if you want it to be namespaced:

```
utils = {}

function utils.slimefunc(...) stuff() end
```

And it will be accessible as `utils.slimefunc`. (If you do that, you'll have to be really careful about not letting your names leak - make judicious use of locals.)

Comment: Well, actually I realized I was using different require syntax, like require(" "); I switched to yours and it found the correct file path but still couldn't find the file. Unfortunately this require makes it look in the wrong places for the other files. I'll post an example.

Comment: My "require syntax" is just shorthand for function calls. If you're calling a function with just a string literal or a table literal (though not a variable containing such), you can replace `function('')` or `function({})` with `function ''` and `function {}`, leaving off the parentheses. It shouldn't make a difference either way, since require is just a normal function. Are you sure your `package.path` setting is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us enough information.  For example, you don't say if `GameObjectUtilities` is defined or what its value is.  (I'm guessing it is set to `true`.)

I highly recommend that you buy the [second edition](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/) of Roberto Ierusalimschy's superb book *Programming in Lua*, which explains the idiomatic use of `require` and `module` very simply and clearly.  It is also an excellent book for anyone using Lua to help get the most out of the language and libraries.  As luck would have it, there is a [free sample chapter](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/chapter15.pdf) which at the moment covers exactly the topic you're looking for.  But buy the book anyway; it is $25 well spent :-)

If you don't want to buy the book, you can read the [free sample chapter](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/chapter15.pdf), and you can also read about [how to do things the "old" way, without `module(...)`](http://www.lua.org/pil/15.1.html), because the [entire previous edition](http://www.lua.org/pil/index.html) is free online.

One possible short answer is that your "utilities" script should probably **create a table** and **return it**.